# Вычленение кусков текста в текстовом файле [Java]

Tags: java, svg, текст, работа-с-текстом

У меня есть SVG файл из которого необходимо вычленить элементарные составляющие такие как:

```
<rect x="0" y="0" width="400" height="400" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="5px" stroke-opacity="0.5"/>
```

и записать их как объекты. Как можно автоматизировать этот процесс быстро и просто?
Имеется в виду как вычленить сам элемент, что я привел в примере, из документа. И как его вычленить если он разнесен на несколько строк.
Например, здесь мой код не считывает элемент path:
`<g>
            <polygon class="st53" points="351.7,230 378,171.9 323,157 316.3,220.4           "/>
            <path class="st1" d="M353.6,166.6c1.2,0.6,2.6,1.2,4.3,1.9c2.3,0.8,5.1,1.6,7.9,2c2.8,0.4,5.8,0.5,8.5,0.3l-1.2-9.5
                c-2.1,0.3-4.5,0.7-6.9,0.9c-2.4,0.2-4.8,0.2-7,0.2c-1.8-0.1-3.4-0.3-4.7-0.4c0.4-0.4,0.8-0.8,1.1-1.2c1.8-1.8,9.6-11.7,11.2-14
                l-6.3-3.9c-0.7,1.3-7,10.4-7.7,11.9c0.2-2.6-1.2-14.5-1.4-17l-7.3,0.9c0.5,3.1,2.9,15.8,3.6,18.7c0.2,0.8,0.3,1.8,0.6,2.8
                c-1.1-0.5-2.5-1.1-4-1.9c-1.9-1-4-2.3-5.9-3.7c-2-1.4-3.9-2.9-5.5-4.3l-5.8,7.6c2.2,1.6,4.8,3,7.4,4.1c2.7,1.1,5.4,1.8,7.8,2.3
                c1.7,0.3,3.3,0.5,4.6,0.6l-7,25.8l-19.7-5.4l-0.8,7.1l18.6,5.1l-7.3,27l6.8,1.8l7.3-27l18.6,5.1l2.9-6.5l-19.7-5.4L353.6,166.6z"
                />
        </g>`

сам код:

```
    try{
        s = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Timur\\Desktop\\SVG\\this_boy_loves_Christmas-4784.svg")));
        //s = s.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");
    }catch(IOException e){
    }

    path_pattern = "<path.*/>";
    pattern = Pattern.compile(path_pattern);
    matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    if (matcher.find()){
        out.println(matcher.group());
    }else{
        out.println("failure");
    }
```

Comment: как насчет регульярных выражений?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor Спасибо, это то что нужно. Но у меня не получается получить элемент если он описан слишком длинно и разнесен на несколько строк. Похоже Matcher анализирует построчно или я чтото не так делаю.

Comment: приложите несколько строчек из вашего файла к телу вопроса, нажав на править

Comment: @SeniorPomidor закинул

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вобщем я использовал регулярные выражения(regex), за что спасибо пользователю SeniorPomidor
Для многострочных совпадений использовал патерн:

```
"<path[^/]*/>"
```